# How do I make a file from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

How do I make a file from a dictionary in python?

For example this is my dictionary: 
dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
How do I make it into the first sentence of a file that shows this?
a,1.b,2.c,3.

Thank you to anyone who answers my question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
f.write('.'.join('{},{}'.format(a, b) for a, b in dict.items())+'.\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
mydict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3} 
with open('dict_file.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(mydict))
```

Hope this helps.